# How do you self sign a macro for Microsoft Office for a non admin user

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, macros, trusted-root-certificates

I am trying to self sign a macro that I wrote for Outlook, and my searches lead to `SelfCert.exe`

I ran `SelfCert.exe` and was able to make a self signed certificate, and inside of Outlook I was able to select that certificate for signing my macro.

The problem is that every time I restart Outlook, my macros are disabled. I think they are disabled because the self signed certificate I created is not installed in my Trusted Root Certification Authorities

My Macro Settings under the Trust Center are set to `Notifications for all macros` which seemed the most appropriate because the only other options are `Disable all macros without notification` `Notifications for digitally signed macros, all other macros disabled` and `Enable all macros`.

I do my day to do work with a non admin account and only log in to the local admin account when needed, so the self signed certificate is associated with my non admin user. If I run `SelfCert.exe` as administrator, I can make a self signed certificate associated with my admin user, but I can't select that certificate to sign my macros in Outlook because I'm running Outlook as my normal non admin account.

If I use mmc to manage certificates, I can only see the certificate generated with the admin user under `Certificates - Current User` -> `Personal` -> `Certificates`, and I can't see how to access the certificate created with my non admin account because I can't use mmc with my non admin account.

How can I get that self signed certificate, created with my non admin account, installed into my Trusted Root Certificate Authorities so I can sign my Outlook macros?

Comment: I'm not sure, but "Notifications for digitally signed macros, all other macros disabled" seems to suggest that signed macros will be enabled. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

I was about to add screenshots to my question when I realized that the security warning popup in Outlook had an option to trust all items from this publisher (referring to my self signed certificate). After selecting that, it looks like my self signed certificate was added to whatever certificate store it needed to be added to for Outlook to trust my macros. Now that I've trusted that certificate I'm not getting the security popup any more, and therefore can't add a screenshot of that popup to my question or to this answer.